# Subgit importing a root directory without standard layout

Tags: git, svn, subgit

I have the following SVN repository structure. This is not by design, someone did something odd before I became involved.

```
https://server/svn/repo
https://server/svn/repo/rootfolder1
https://server/svn/repo/rootfolder2
https://server/svn/repo/trunk
https://server/svn/repo/trunk/trunkfolder1
https://server/svn/repo/trunk/trunkfolder2
```

I am attempting to import the two folders `rootfolder1` and `rootfolder2` into a Git repository (I will then split them off to separate repositories using git-filter-branch).

Running `subgit import --svn-url https://server/svn/repo repo-root`, I'm left with a Git repository with `trunkfolder1` and `trunkfolder2`. Passing `--trunk repo` gives me an empty Git repository. Running as `subgit import --svn-url --trunk repo https://server/svn repo-root` gives me the following error:

```
IMPORT FAILED

error: svn: E175002: PROPFIND of '/': 405 Method Not Allowed (https://server)
```

I also tried `subgit --import --trunk . --svn-url https://server/svn/repo repo-root` however subgit complains about the `--trunk` parameter.

Any suggestions on a solution to this problem?

Comment: "I will then split them off to separate repositories using git-filter-branch" use `git subtree split` instead of filter-branch

Comment: ah didn't know about that - I was reading an old tutorial maybe. I've already used `git filter branch` on a bunch of other repos. Is there a difference in the result?

Comment: subtree split is much better. Read here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53695232/git-split-existing-repository-into-submodules/53695584#53695584

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you eventually intend to have those 'rootfolders' into separate repositories, then it's reasonable to import them into different Git repositories on the import stage, I think. It could be done by the following two commands:

```
subgit import --trunk rootfolder1 --username <svn user name> --password <svn user password> --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --svn-url https://server/svn/repo <GIT_REPO>

subgit import --trunk rootfolder2 --username <svn user name> --password <svn user password> --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --svn-url https://server/svn/repo <GIT_REPO_2>
```

In this case, 'rootfolder1' will be imported into GIT_REPO and 'rootfolder2' into GIT_REPO_2, so you won't need to split them.

In addition, I'd recommend providing an authors file during import so that SVN users are translated to suitable Git users, find more details here:

https://subgit.com/documentation/import-book.html#authors_file

Importing both 'rootfolders' into a single Git repository is also possible, but it requires extra steps to get rid of 'trunk':

- prepare a new Git repo for the import:

  subgit configure https://server/svn/repo GIT_REPO
- open SubGit configuration file in a text editor:

  GIT_REPO/subgit/config
- change mapping configuration in the following way:

  ```
  [svn]

      trunk:refs/heads/master
      excludePath = /trunk
  ```

  save and close the file.
- run the import:

  subgit import GIT_REPO

In this case, GIT_REPO will only contain 'rootfolders' as 'trunk' is excluded by 'excludePath' directive.

Comment: Hi thanks for this, I got it working using your first approach, exporting the folders individually using `--trunk`. Works great